# Scraping with BeautifulSoup: Scraping a specific column in a table, from a HTML page

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get a hold of the data under the second column having the code "CATAC2021", where "aaaa" are the four letter that follow (eg. aaaa, aaab, etc) on the [Shakemap Site](http://shakemapcam.ethz.ch/archive/) using Python. These are the ID of the event.

I have tried to use the following code below to access the second column of the table and retrieve the ID data from the row but I seem to be having no success so far. Does anyone know where I have gone wrong/how to correct this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

page = request.urlopen('http://shakemapcam.ethz.ch/archive/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

desired_table = soup.findAll('table')[2]

# Find the columns you want data from
headers = desired_table.findAll('th')
desired_columns = []
for th in headers:
    if 'CATAC2021' in th.string:
        desired_columns.append([headers.index(th), th.getText()])

# Iterate through each row grabbing the data from the desired columns
rows = desired_table.findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    row_name = row.findNext('th').getText()
    for column in desired_columns:
        print(cells[column[0]].text, row_name, column[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use pandas here to grab the table, then use regex to pull out the pattern (following the four digit and before the first  `/`. Note though that ther eis an `Event ID` column, so just be sure you know the difference. I named it `eventId`.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://shakemapcam.ethz.ch/archive/'
df = pd.read_html(url, header =0)[-1]
df['eventID'] = df['Name/Epicenter'].str.extract(r'(.*)\d{4}(.*)(\s//?.*)(//?.*)')[1]
df['prefix'] = df['Name/Epicenter'].str.extract(r'(.*)\d{4}(.*)(\s//?.*)(//?.*)')[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df[['Name/Epicenter','prefix','eventId']])
                                      Name/Epicenter     prefix eventId
0         CATAC2021efod / 6.354496002 / -76.18144226      CATAC    efod
1         CATAC2021edxe / 15.67289066 / -93.40866852      CATAC    edxe
2         CATAC2021ebzg / 9.406171799 / -84.55581665      CATAC    ebzg
3         CATAC2021eayx / 14.03658199 / -92.30122375      CATAC    eayx
4         CATAC2021eayx / 14.03546429 / -92.30183411      CATAC    eayx
                                             ...        ...     ...
1574   ineterloc2018acor / 12.21397209 / -86.7282486  ineterloc    acor
1575  ineterloc2018acor / 12.21113586 / -86.73029327  ineterloc    acor
1576  ineterloc2018acor / 12.20839691 / -86.73122406  ineterloc    acor
1577  ineterloc2018aatd / 16.59416389 / -86.35289764  ineterloc    aatd
1578  ineterloc2018aatd / 16.64553833 / -86.26078796  ineterloc    aatd

[1579 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your reply. It works great and exactly what I needed!

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could retrieve the CATAC2021.... column. So, if I have an geojson file in my computer that has the name CATAC2021eayx, how could I compare it to the ID's within the list and use an if statement to say if it is within this column or not? Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @LiamHems, not sure what you mean. Can you clarify? So are you saying you want just the CATAC2021 part in a separate column?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would only like the CATAC2021 part in a column where I can use an 'if' statement within the column and say that if the ID on my computer matches the ID within this column, then it runs a separate python script I have. If the ID on my computer does not match the ID within this column, then I will tell Python to end the script. So, just being able to access this column alone is good enough with me :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It is kindly appreciated